# Net::GitHub::V3 and Proxy settings

Tags: perl, github, cpan, github-api

I am trying to connect to github using [`Net::GitHub`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::GitHub)

my code is something like the below :

```
use Net::GitHub::V3;
my $gh = Net::GitHub::V3->new(
    login => 'myuser', pass => 'mypassword'
);

my $search = $gh->search;
my %data = $search->repositories({ q => 'repname' });
```

i get the following error message :

Can't connect to api.github.com:443 at Net/GitHub/V3/Search.pm line 27.

- worth to mention i am using this mdoule behind a proxy

do someone familiar how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you put your whole script up here, and if there are details about using proxies that might be relevant, please add them to your question. I don't get any errors when using the code you've pasted above.

Comment: this is the whole script only missing the use .. before the code and the real user name and password ,this script is used behind a proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just uploaded a new version of Net::GitHub to CPAN. 0.69.

now you can do something like

$gh->ua->proxy('https', 'socks://127.0.0.1:9050');

check [examples/proxy.pl](https://github.com/fayland/perl-net-github/blob/master/examples/proxy.pl) $gh->ua is LWP::UserAgent.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort I will download the new version and try it.

Comment: When i tried to use LWP::Useragent proxy using the above method i get bad request but when used the LWP Environment variables it works :BEGIN {   $Net::HTTPS::SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = "Net::SSL";  
  $ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://myproxy:8080'; 
 $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0
 }                                                                   Thank you very much for your help

Comment: the above code is using socks proxy. and the code you showed is using HTTPS proxy. so if you want the above code works like yours, change the socks:// to https:// and it will work also. ty